# How to pass multiple parameters into HttpGet Method in ASP.NET CORE MVC?

Tags: api, model-view-controller, parameters, http-get, webapi

Is it possible to pass multiple parameters into HttpGet Method? I want to pass Id or Username to get the user's details. But when I try to do it, I got this error:

> Microsoft.AspNetCore.Routing.Matching.AmbiguousMatchException: The
> request matched multiple endpoints. Matches:
>
> AuthenticationAPI.Controllers.AuthenticationController.Details
> (AuthenticationAPI)
> AuthenticationAPI.Controllers.AuthenticationController.Detail
> (AuthenticationAPI)    at
> Microsoft.AspNetCore.Routing.Matching.DefaultEndpointSelector.ReportAmbiguity(CandidateState[]
> candidateState)    at
> Microsoft.AspNetCore.Routing.Matching.DefaultEndpointSelector.ProcessFinalCandidates(HttpContext
> httpContext, CandidateState[] candidateState)    at
> Microsoft.AspNetCore.Routing.Matching.DefaultEndpointSelector.Select(HttpContext
> httpContext, CandidateState[] candidateState)    at
> Microsoft.AspNetCore.Routing.Matching.DfaMatcher.MatchAsync(HttpContext
> httpContext)    at
> Microsoft.AspNetCore.Routing.Matching.DataSourceDependentMatcher.MatchAsync(HttpContext
> httpContext)    at
> Microsoft.AspNetCore.Routing.EndpointRoutingMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext
> httpContext)    at
> Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.AuthenticationMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext
> context)    at
> Swashbuckle.AspNetCore.SwaggerUI.SwaggerUIMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext
> httpContext)    at
> Swashbuckle.AspNetCore.Swagger.SwaggerMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext
> httpContext, ISwaggerProvider swaggerProvider)    at
> Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.DeveloperExceptionPageMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext
> context)

So, can I know is there any way to do this?

Comment: This is totally possible, but would you please paste in your action methods, as the error suggests, that there might be an easy fix, as you seem to have a little routing problem.

Answer (score 1):

Use Attribute Routing

```
[Route("/api/controller/{parameter}/{id}")] public async
IActionResult(string parameter, int id){

}
```